# GraphQL Unknown argument "limit" on field even though it was defined in the schema

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm stuck when I try to pass an argument parameter on a field. I got this error message back :
`"message": "Unknown argument \"limit\" on field \"User.followers\"."`

```
query {
  getUser(username: "johnsmith") { # <= this argument is ok
    username
    followers(limit: 10) { # <= but this one is not
      users {
        username
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Yet I think I defined that argument correctly in my schema.

```
  type Query {
    getUser(username: ID!): User!
    followers(limit: Int!): Followers!
  }
```

```
Query: {
    getUser: (_, { username }) => getUser(username),
  },
  User: {
    followers: ({ username }, args) => getAllFollowers(username, args)
  }
}
```

My Graphql Playground auto-generated docs, however, mentions the "limit" argument:

```
followers(
limit: Int!
): Followers!
```

Did I miss something ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `followers` field on your `Query` type is not the same field as the `followers` field on your `User` type.